# Schedule a call to a cloud function at a later date

Tags: parse-platform

In my Parse app, I have an Event class with a date field, and I would like to send a push notification to all the users who have subscribed to this event when the event date is due. My Google search has led me to several leads:

- Parse.com's background jobs are nice but it seems I can only schedule them from the web interface, not from a cloud code function (afterSave of my Event class for example)
- Some people mentioned Iron.io's IronWorker, but the service is pretty expensive ($30 a month) and I still don't understand how I can schedule a one-shot (not recurrent) script using their API
- I also found easycron.com but their API needs a crontab expression and I only have a Javascript Date

Are there any other options to do that? Any example out there on how to set that up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested I am writing this as an separate answer.

You could keep the scheduling of your notifications to the client and use something like UILocalNotification to schedule the cloud code method call.

One caveat, as you mentioned, is someone tampering with local date and time. When planning you should keep in mind if that's a tradeoff you can accept.

Answer (score 0):

This example is taken from the javascript sdk guide. Seems as if you can specify a push_time property. [For reference](https://parse.com/docs/push_guide#scheduled/JavaScript) 
You can use this in cloud code as well.

```
var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
query.equalTo('user_id', 'user_123');

Parse.Push.send({
  where: query,
  data: {
    alert: "You previously created a reminder for the game today"
  },
  push_time: new Date(2014, 12, 11)
}, {
  success: function() {
    // Push was successful
  },
  error: function(error) {
    // Handle error
  }
});
```

Hope this helps you out. :)

Comment: This is nice, but I'm not sure I can plan a long time in advance. I saw some discussions on the forum that it was limited in time. And even then, it would mean that I need to update push notifications when somebody unreergisters from the event, and plan push notifications individually. That's why I would need a way to call a cloud functions that sends push notifications now to all those who are registered now.

Comment: Indeed, the documentation says "The scheduled time cannot be in the past, and can be up to two weeks in the future."

Comment: @Sebastien
okay i see, what you could maybe do is set up your custom express logic on parse and use something like node-schedule to schedule the function call, but im not sure this would work as intended. Otherwise i could think of scheduling the call from a the client side - e.g with a local notification(iOS).

Comment: very good suggestion about local notifications! Indeed I don't need to go to the server to send those notifications. The only problem with local notification is that the user can simply mess with its local date and time to trigger the notification at the wrong time, but in my use case it's not such a big deal. Thanks a lot. If you add this as an answer, I will accept it.